# How can you get the payload of a push notification if app is already running in the background when the user taps the notification?

Tags: ios, push-notification

If a push notification is displayed to the user and the user taps it and the app is brought to the foreground from a background state then **how can the app get the payload of the notification**?

Because the app is already running `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`: won't get called and because the app was in the background when the push arrived `didReceiveRemoteNotification`: won't have been called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"because the app was in the background when the push arrived didReceiveRemoteNotification: won't have been called."

This, or didReceiveRemoteNotification:withExpirationHandler, should get called if the app is in the background and gets switched to the foreground when the user taps on the notification.

However I got into a situation when this wasn't working as the reason was the content of the push was incorrect, I can't remember the details but double check what's in there.

Answer (score 1):

There are two places so I usually make a method that handles both something like this:

```
- (void)handleMessageFromRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

Then in: `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) {
        [self handleMessageFromRemoteNotification:launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]];
}
```

also in: `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`

`[self handleMessageFromRemoteNotification:userInfo`

If you want to do something different if the app is running check application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive in didReceiveRemoteNotification

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple documentation the method didFinishLauchingWithOptions: is called when the user taps the action button of the notification.

> As a result of the presented notification, the user taps the action
>   button of the alert or taps (or clicks) the application icon. If the
>   action button is tapped (on a device running iOS), the system launches
>   the application and the application calls its delegate’s
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method (if implemented); it
>   passes in the notification payload (for remote notifications) or the
>   local-notification object (for local notifications).

Then in this method it is easy to recover the content of the notification by doing for example :

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif =
    [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (localNotif) {
    NSString *itemName = [localNotif.userInfo objectForKey:ToDoItemKey];
    [viewController displayItem:itemName];  // custom method
    app.applicationIconBadgeNumber = localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber-1;
}
```

Comment: The method isn't being called if the app is already launched. My app is being switched from the background to the foreground when the user taps the notification but that method isn't being invoked. Only if I terminate the app before tapping the notification is it being invoked, (and the launch option is UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey)