# how to get push notification payload data when the app is in background in ionic framework,

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, ionic-framework, google-cloud-messaging

Hi I'm able to get the push notification in my ionic android app. I can get the push notification when app is running or in background or closed.

I am alerting the notification payload data. When app is running when I send the push notification to the app I'm getting the alert with payload data. 
When the app is in background or closed I get the notification. When I tap on the notification in the notification tray (i got to the app via notification tray ). I get the alert in the app when app opens.

But when app is in background or closed, I get the notification but when I got to the app via app icon or recent apps(not tapping the notification in the tray) I cannot get the alert.

I want to get the payload data when I go to the app by tapping the icon or recent apps too.

Please help me.

Comment: Try to check this SO ticket [23481629](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481629/how-can-you-get-the-payload-of-a-push-notification-if-app-is-already-running-in?rq=1) and [30938319](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938319/implementing-push-notification-in-ionic-app?rq=1)
 if it can help you:)

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? Im having similar issue